# How to Git rebase with only one "verification"

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, rebase

Hello ! everyone I need help please...
I have :

- (master)
- (mybranch-actually)
  - commit old-1 (today)
  - commit old-2  (yesterday)
  - commit old-3  (1950...)

I want squash all my old commit with rebase
But my branch is very old... and i have lot of useless commit.
and when i do

```
$ .../.../..(mybranch-actually): git rebase -i origin/master
```

it makes me a difference check for each commit (old-1, old-2, old-3).
 But is
it's useless, I would like him to **check only my most recent** **commit (old-1 with master)**
and ** directly squash all other commit in mybranch-actually**  without verification

Comment: and `git merge --squash` doesn't pull it off?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to keep `old-1` as a separate commit, but squash everything from `old-2` back to some starting point into a single commit. And you don't want to bother with an interactive rebase to do it.

I'm sure there are clever ways to do that, but here's a simple recipe. I'll start with this situation:

```
* 699abbb (HEAD -> actual) e
* 6c924b6 d
* 51c7c64 c
* 2f15c0c b
* ae36341 a
| * c785b2c (main) second
|/  
* e77cdf8 start
```

My goal is to keep `e` but turn `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` into a single commit, which I'll call `squash`. Here we go. Notice that I am actually on `actual` to begin with:

```
git switch -c temp HEAD~1
git reset --soft e77cdf8
git commit -msquash
```

We now have this:

```
* 56d04c1 (HEAD -> temp) squash
| * 699abbb (actual) e
| * 6c924b6 d
| * 51c7c64 c
| * 2f15c0c b
| * ae36341 a
|/  
| * c785b2c (main) second
|/  
* e77cdf8 start
```

This may not look like any improvement, but in fact `squash` is the same as `a` and `b` and `c` and `d` squashed together. So all we need to do is throw them away and stick `e` on the end of `temp`, right after `squash`. Okay then:

```
git switch actual
git rebase --onto temp actual~1 actual
git branch -d temp
```

And now we have this:

```
* f259d42 (HEAD -> actual) e
* 56d04c1 squash
| * c785b2c (main) second
|/  
* e77cdf8 start
```

Since `squash` is, as I have said, a summation of the old `a` and `b` and `c` and `d`, this is exactly what you were looking for. Now if you want to do more with `actual`, you can do so, but the branch history looks the way you want it.

Comment: It seems so complicated to me but really exactly what I'm looking for.

I will try this, thank you very much for your help and for the time you spent.

Comment: Well, in real life there might be a shorter way. Personally I would just use the interactive rebase that you didn't want to use. But it seems to be a presupposition of your question that you don't want to do that.